# Scenebuilder rejects Webview in custom control

Tags: javafx, webview, custom-controls, scenebuilder

I'm creating a rich text control that uses a WebView for display and HTMLEditor for editing. When I tried to add the control to Scenebuilder's custom controls an exception was thrown:

```
Exception for: com/spindotta/jfx/control/text/RichTextArea.class
```

javafx.fxml.LoadException:

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = LibraryFolderWatcher([library folder location])
```

...

```
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.checkThread(WebEngine.java:1216)
```

...

It seems that Scenebuilder tries to instantiate a WebView, which in turn tries to instantiate a WebEngine which seems to require an FX application thread, which the custom control doesn't generate.

Would be grateful for any ideas/workaround.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SceneBuilder has a built in mechanism that checks all the jars in the user library looking for custom controls.

For any given jar, that implies checking all its classes, looking for possible controls: concrete classes that are assignable from `Node`. Then it creates an instance for these and try to load it on the class path. If it works, it will be added to the library panel.

In case of your custom control, that includes a `WebView` node, this means that when your control is being checked by SceneBuilder, a new instance of `WebView` will be done. At this point you'll get the exception you mentioned:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = LibraryFolderWatcher()
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.checkThread(WebEngine.java:1216)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:856)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:845)
at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:271)
```

So the easy solution for this will be allowing the custom control to be loaded in the JavaFX application thread when being loaded in design mode by SceneBuilder.

This small custom control works for me:

```
public class WebControl extends StackPane {

    private WebView webView;

    public WebControl() {
        if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
            init();
        } else {
            // Intended for SceneBuilder
            Platform.runLater(this::init);
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");
        getChildren().add(webView);
    }

}
```

[image: WebControl]

Comment: @JPereda - Thanks for your reply, and especially for explaining the process step-by-step and how that lead to the exception. It's exactly what I thought was happening, but your explanation is more articulate which is probably because you know what you're doing and I ... don't. Relatively new here, so I don't know how to give you credit, would be grateful if you could comment back as to how. Thanks!

Comment: Just accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer) as valid and up vote it if you like. That will help others to find it as a valid source in case they run in the same problem.

Comment: Bro, you are a legend. Thank you!